# Decrease image size in product view page

Tags: magento

we have backend condfiguration to resize product images. so we set 850 * 850 for our images.

[image]

now in product view page images are showing in very large size, i want to reduce it to 350 * 350 size

we are using below code :

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same query asked in your previous post, check the previous post. You need to modify your css

## etalage .etalage_thumb_image{height:350 !important; width:350 !important;}